# dojo 1.8: populate select box with items from database including null values

Tags: dojo

Hi I just want to populate the select or comboBox.
I am able to populate both with the searchAttr to any string from JSON. But not so when there are null values.

JSON string :

```
[{"batch":"0000001000"},{"batch":"0000"},{"batch":""},{"batch":null}]
```

dojo code:

```
var selBatch = new ComboBox //located at the left side of the page and it is the second select box in a row
(
    {   id:'ID_selBatch',
        value:'',
        searchAttr:'batch',
        placeHolder:'Select...',
        style:{width:'150px'},
    },  'node_selBatch'
);

on(selTest, 'change', function(valueCard)
{
    var selectedTest = this.get('displayedValue');
    var selBatch = registry.byId('ID_selBatch');
    console.debug('Connecting to gatherbatches.php ...');
    request.post('gatherbatches.php',
    {   data:{nameDB:registry.byId('ID_selPCBA').value, nameCard : valueCard},
        handleAs: "json"}).then
        (
            function(response)
                {
                    var memoStore2 = new Memory({data:response});
                    selBatch.set('store', memoStore2);
                    selBatch.set('value','');
                    console.debug('List of batches per Test is completed! Good OK! ');
                },
            function(error)
                {
                    alert("Batch's Error:"+error);
                    console.debug('Problem: Listing batches per Test in select Test is BAD!');
                }
        );
     selBatch.startup();

});
```

Error :

```
TypeError: _32[this.searchAttr] is null
          defer()                             -> _WidgetBase.js (line 331)
          _3()                                ->  dojo.js (line 15)
          _f.hitch(this,fcn)();               -> _WidgetBase.js (line 331)
```

Please advise though it might strange to have null values populate in the select box but  these null values are related to data in other columns in database, so the null values included so that I can apply mysql scripts later. Or do you have other better suggestion?

Clement

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `QueryFilter` [as in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/DJg2e/6/) to achieve what you want, but it might be simpler to have two data items. Your original model with possibly `null` `batch` properties, and the model you pass to the store which is used by the `ComboBox`.

But anyway, this can work:

```
function createQueryFilter(originalQuery, filter) {
    return function () {
        var originalResults = originalQuery.apply(this, arguments);
        var results = originalResults.filter(filter);
        return QueryResults(results);
    };
}
```

and

```
var memoStore = new Memory({
    data: data
});
memoStore.query = createQueryFilter(memoStore.query, function (item) {
    console.log(item);
    return !!item.batch;
});
```

and the dummy data:

```
function createData1() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        data.push({
            name: "" + i,
            batch: (0 === i % 2) ? "batch" + i : null
        });
    }
    return data;
}
```

Screenshot. The odd numbered batch items are null in my example.

[image]